# Impossible to get file properties from target/classes folder

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have tried to use Maven git commit id Plugin, it generates an git.properties file in target/classes folder. I have followed this guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-git-information but I can't get the file, I get notFoundFile exception.
It seems that the file has to be under src/main/resources to be read.
I have tried other solution too like

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("git.properties");
```

But the resource is alway null

Comment: It is true. The same here.